# error while running "source .vimrc"

Tags: bash, vim, ubuntu-12.04

i am having a simple vimrc file when i run "source .vimrc" in ubuntu I am getting the following error.

```
$ source .vimrc 
bash: .vimrc: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `"syntax"'
bash: .vimrc: line 3: `if has("syntax")'
```

Here is my script file

```
set term=builtin_ansi
set nu
if has("syntax")
    syntax on
endif
```

I do have syntax installed in my vim.

```
vim --version | grep syntax
vim: /home/shankaran/src/ns/service/build/dp/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
vim: /home/shankaran/src/ns/service/build/dp/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
-sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You tried to source your Vim configuration file from bash. Do it from Vim:

```
$ vim
:source /path/to/.vimrc
```

If it's located at `~/.vimrc`, Vim will source that file automatically.

Comment: @user2421350 What is "it"?  Open `vim`?  `source` the vimrc file?  Please help the person that is trying to help you by being explicit.

Comment: See sometimes it works from the terminal and sometimes it works from inside vim i.e. `:source .vimrc`.

Comment: @Astrid, those are two different commands in two different contexts that happen to have the same name and do roughly the same thing but with different files. In Vim you source vimscript files; in your shell you source shell script files.

Comment: @romainl - did not know that, nice. So which one, for final clarity, should I run when I have updated my `~/.vimrc` file?

Comment: The one in Vim: `:source $MYVIMRC`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do
    :so $MYVIMRC

Just type 
    :so $MY[tab] 
and it will autocomplete for you.