# error when trying to implement vim-plug in .vimrc

Tags: linux, vim

I am trying to install vim-plug and I followed your instructions in your tutorial. I have written in .vimrc like so:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/autoload')
call plug#end()
```

but I get the following errors:

```
-bash: /Users/user/.vimrc: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /Users/user/.vimrc: line 18: `call plug#begin('~/.vim/autoload')'
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error while running "source .vimrc"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651114/error-while-running-source-vimrc)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+bash+vimrc%3A+syntax+error+near+unexpected+token

Answer (score 1):

Note how the error messages you're receiving start with `-bash:`, which indicates these lines are being parsed by bash, not Vim.

Can you somehow explain how that is happening?

Are you by any chance sourcing this file from your shell? Are you referring to `.vimrc` from somewhere? How are you starting Vim exactly? Do you have some commands in your `.vimrc` around these lines that would cause them to be passed to a shell?

Figuring out how this is happening should make it easy for you to figure out how to fix it.